# How to determine the version number of an executable or DLL file using typescript?

Tags: typescript, dll, exe

How can I determine the version number of a given executable or DLL file in Typescript? The file is given as a filename such as `C:\Sample.dll` or `C:\Sample.exe`.

Comment: What do you mean, version?

Comment: @kaya3, version means File Version of an executable or deliverable.
For example, Right click on exe file ->click on  properties -> Go to Details tab ->there File Version property will be displayed with version number as value.
I need to get that version number using typescript.

Comment: So specifically you are looking to find the version number of a Windows executable or DLL file, not just any given file?

Comment: yes, mainly for executable and DLL

Comment: Where are you running this TypeScript? In a browser? In Electron? In the Windows Shell (ActiveScript)? In a HTA?

Comment: For VSTS extension, I'm using typescript for validation. So this script will run on Azure hosted agent/OnPrem. Any solution will help a lot.